# Как сделать, чтобы в выходные выводилось одно всплывающее окно, а ночью другое.

Tags: javascript

Недавно у меня возник вопрос "Как создать всплывающее окно, которое будет выводиться только в заданное время". С этим вопросом мне помог пользователь форума Rules. Код, который он мне предоставил:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta name="charset" content="utf-8">
    <title>Окно</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #mywindow{
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 25%;
                    left: 25%;
                    width: 50%;
                    height: 50%;
                    background-color: #FFF9AE;
                    visibility: hidden;
                }
        #closewin{
            position: absolute;
            top: 3px;
            right: 3px;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            background-color: #FFF9AE;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
                #mywindow2{
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 25%;
                    left: 25%;
                    width: 50%;
                    height: 50%;
                    background-color: #FFF9AE;
                    visibility: hidden;
                }
        #closewin2{
            position: absolute;
            top: 3px;
            right: 3px;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            background-color: #FFF9AE;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
    <script>

function showWindow(){
            var myWindow = document.getElementById("mywindow");
            var myWindow2 = document.getElementById("mywindow2");
            var nowDate = new Date();
            if(nowDate.getDay() == 0 || nowDate.getDay() == 6){
                myWindow.style.visibility = "visible";
            }

            if(nowDate.getDay() == 1 || nowDate.getDay() == 2 || nowDate.getDay() == 3 || nowDate.getDay() == 4 || nowDate.getDay() == 5 || ( nowDate.getHours() <= 8 || nowDate.getHours() >= 21 )){
                myWindow2.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        }
        function closeWin(){
            var myWindow = document.getElementById("mywindow");
            myWindow.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        window.onload = showWindow;

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mywindow"><div id="closewin" onclick="closeWin()">Закрыть</div>Выходной</div>
<div id="mywindow2"><div id="closewin" onclick="closeWin()">Закрыть</div>Ночь</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Теперь вопрос в другом: как сделать так, чтобы ночью всплывало одно окно, а в выходные - другое.

Comment: за тебя код написать что ли? нет, давай сам дружок, а если что не получится можешь спросить, но код за тебя ни кто писать не будет

Comment: Насколько я помню, ночь - это тоже "заданное время", не? А значит ничего принципиально нового и отличного от того, что у вас уже есть, вам писать не придётся.

Comment: А хотя ... Правильно сказал  @johniek_comp, @Pavlik290592 вы помоему в JavaScript Null или даже Undefined :) А если серьёзно я вам код пишу а деньги получаете вы! Так не пойдёт попробуйте сами это организовать а если не получится попросите помощь (ведь там просто скопипастить и изменить надо)

Comment: Rules. Я деньги не получаю. Я делаю свой сайт. Да копировал я. Так у меня начинает то только окно выходного дня показываться, то окно ночное. Сколько разбирался, так и не понял, почему.

Comment: Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: >Так у меня начинает то только окно выходного дня показываться, то окно ночное. Сколько разбирался, так и не понял, почему.

А вы код ваш приведите я исправлю... (не жалко просто капитализм)

Comment: Я бы с радостью, да только комментарий не вмещает столько текста.

Comment: Вот теперь помогу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я счас занят вот примерный код потом подредактирую...

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="charset" content="utf-8">
    <title>Окно</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #mywindow1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        left: 25%;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        background-color: #FFF9AE;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #closewin1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 3px;
        right: 3px;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        background-color: #FFF9AE;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #mywindow2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        left: 25%;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        background-color: #FFF9AE;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #closewin2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 3px;
        right: 3px;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        background-color: #FFF9AE;
        text-decoration: underline;
    } </style>
    <script>
        function showWindow() {
            var myWindow1 = document.getElementById("mywindow1");
            var myWindow2 = document.getElementById("mywindow2");
            var nowDate = new Date();
            if (nowDate.getDay() == 0 || nowDate.getDay() == 6) {
                myWindow1.style.visibility = "visible";
            }

            else if (nowDate.getHours() <= 8 || nowDate.getHours() >= 21 ) {
                myWindow2.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        }
        function closeWin(obj) {
            var myWindow = obj.parentNode;
            myWindow.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        window.onload = showWindow;

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mywindow1">
    <div id="closewin1" onclick="closeWin(this)">Закрыть</div>
    Выходной
</div>
<div id="mywindow2">
    <div id="closewin2" onclick="closeWin(this)">Закрыть</div>
    Ночь
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Только я разницы не вижу.

Comment: И окошко не закрывается. Ну это мелочь.

Comment: Всё (готовился к поступлению в лицей) вот исправил (забыл дописать что надо закрыть родителя крестика а не сам крестик:) ) А разница в том что у вас столько всяких || когда можно обойтись одним else и ещё во многом но мне пора спать примите ответ